# Ajuda com o Gulpjs

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

Estou tendo um pequeno problema com as tasks do gulp. Estou tentando escutas as alterações dos arquivos com watch e atualizar o browser com browser sync.

Segue o código:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var pug         = require('gulp-pug');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('./sass/*scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', function(err){console.log(err.message); })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
});


gulp.task('pug', function(){
    return gulp.src('./views/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/pages'))
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function(){
    return browserSync.init(['./dist/pages','./dist/css/*css', './dist/js/*js'], {
        server:{
            baseDir: './'
        }
    })
});

gulp.task('default', ['pug', 'sass', 'browserSync'], function(){
    gulp.watch('./')
});
```

Minha Hierarquia de pastas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparece a mensagem no navegador:

```
Cannot GET /
```

Answer (score 2):

Pessoal consegui arrumar essa bronca!
Irei postar o código e a explicação para que poça ajudar outras pessoas.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var pug         = require('gulp-pug');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('./sass/*scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', function(err){console.log(err.message); })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
});


gulp.task('pug', function(){
    return gulp.src('./views/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/pages'))
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function(){
    return browserSync.init(['./dist/pages/*.html','./dist/css/*.css', './dist/js/*.js'], {
        server:{
            baseDir: './',
            index: './dist/pages/index.html'
        }
    })
});

gulp.task('default', ['pug', 'sass', 'browserSync'], function(){
    gulp.watch(['./sass/*scss','./views/*pug'], ['sass', 'pug'])
});
```

Estavam faltando alguns detalhes, como por exemplo:
1 - Colocar o '.' nas extensões dos arquivos

```
browserSync.init(['./dist/pages/*.html','./dist/css/*.css', './dist/js/*.js']
```

2 - Especificar no gulp.watch o que eu queria que ele escutasse

```
gulp.watch(['./sass/*scss','./views/*pug'], ['sass', 'pug'])
```

Agora esta tudo funcionando ok!

Comment: Obrigado por postas a resposta.

Comment: De nada @AndrewRibeiro :D